# ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs.TypeError: str.replace is not a function while running with AOT or Webpack

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, uglifyjs, aot

While running the angular app using AOT I am getting the following error:

ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs.TypeError: str.replace is not a function

It was working fine day before yesterday.

I am using the following versions:

node v6.11.5
npm  v3.10.10

Comment: i think this is an `uglify-es` npm package bug. Try using version 3.3.5. `npm install uglify-es@3.3.5 --save-dev`

Comment: It worked.. Thanks :)